# Nested ifelse with varying columns in data.table

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, dplyr

I need to compute a "best value" for each row of some columns of a `data.table`. The best value for each row is the value of the first non-NA column in the given order of selected columns.

As a requirement, the columns to include may vary by order or number. In addition, the name of the column giving the best value should be stored for each row.

#### Example data

With

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
n <- 7
set.seed(1234)
dt <- sample.int(100, n*5, replace = TRUE) %>% 
  ifelse(. < 35, NA, .) %>% 
  matrix(, nrow = n) %>% 
  as.data.table()
```

the sample `data.table` is

```
   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1: NA NA NA NA 84
2: 63 67 84 NA NA
3: 61 52 NA NA 46
4: 63 70 NA NA NA
5: 87 55 NA 82 NA
6: 65 NA NA 53 51
7: NA 93 NA 92 NA
```

The columns to be included in the given order are

```
selected_cols <- c("V3", "V4", "V1")
```

#### Expected result with hard-coded nested `ifelse`

The hardcoded version

```
dt[, best_value := ifelse(!is.na(V3), V3, ifelse(!is.na(V4), V4, V1))]
```

will give the expected result for the best value

```
   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 best_value
1: NA NA NA NA 84         NA
2: 63 67 84 NA NA         84
3: 61 52 NA NA 46         61
4: 63 70 NA NA NA         63
5: 87 55 NA 82 NA         82
6: 65 NA NA 53 51         53
7: NA 93 NA 92 NA         92
```

but it still doesn't show from which of the columns the best value was taken.

In row 2 column `V3` already has a non-NA value. For rows 5, 6, and 7, the values from column `V4` are taken. Finally, column `V1` gives the values for rows 3 and 4 where both `V3` and `V4`  are NA. Row 1 contains a NA because all columns under consideration are NA.

#### Flexible approach with `for` loop

Using a `for` loop over the selected columns and some `data.table` features

```
dt[, best_value := NA_integer_]
dt[, best_col := NA_character_]
for (x in selected_cols) {
  dt[is.na(best_value), best_col := ifelse(!is.na(.SD), names(.SD), NA), .SDcols = x]
  dt[is.na(best_value), best_value:= .SD, .SDcols = x]
}
```

we get the full expected result

```
   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 best_value best_col
1: NA NA NA NA 84         NA       NA
2: 63 67 84 NA NA         84       V3
3: 61 52 NA NA 46         61       V1
4: 63 70 NA NA NA         63       V1
5: 87 55 NA 82 NA         82       V4
6: 65 NA NA 53 51         53       V4
7: NA 93 NA 92 NA         92       V4
```

In addition, the vector of columns to be included can be changed easily.

#### Question

However, the approach with a `for` loop with two statements looks rather clumsy to me and not very `data.table`-like.

Is there a better way to achieve these result with `data.table` or `dplyr` or even in base R?

Comment: `apply(dt[c('V3', 'V4', 'V1')], 1, function(x){x[min(which(!is.na(x)))]})`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Working on your 'for' loop and taking advantage of the `list` - `data.table` structure:

```
ans_col = rep_len(NA_character_, nrow(dt))
ans_val = rep_len(NA_real_, nrow(dt))
for(col in selected_cols) {
    i = is.na(ans_col) & (!is.na(dt[[col]]))
    ans_col[i] = col
    ans_val[i] = dt[[col]][i]   
}
data.frame(ans_val, ans_col)
#  ans_val ans_col
#1      NA    <NA>
#2      84      V3
#3      61      V1
#4      63      V1
#5      82      V4
#6      53      V4
#7      92      V4
```

Answer (score 5):

We specify the 'selected_cols' in `.SDcols`, grouped by sequence of rows, we `unlist` the Subset of Data.table (`unlist(.SD)`), get the index of the first non-NA value ('j1'), use that to get the 'v1' corresponding to the index and  the column names, assign (`:=`) to create two new columns.

```
dt[, c("best_val", "best_col") := {v1 <- unlist(.SD)
     j1 <- which(!is.na(v1))[1]
     list(v1[j1], names(.SD)[j1]) },
        .SDcols = selected_cols, by = 1:nrow(dt)]
dt
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 best_val best_col
#1: NA NA NA NA 84       NA       NA
#2: 63 67 84 NA NA       84       V3
#3: 61 52 NA NA 46       61       V1
#4: 63 70 NA NA NA       63       V1
#5: 87 55 NA 82 NA       82       V4
#6: 65 NA NA 53 51       53       V4
#7: NA 93 NA 92 NA       92       V4
```

---

If we are using `base R`, row/column indexing can be used with `max.col`

```
setDF(dt)
j1 <-  max.col(!is.na(dt[selected_cols]), "first")
best_value <- dt[selected_cols][cbind(1:nrow(dt),j1)]
best_value
#[1] NA 84 61 63 82 53 92
j2 <- j1*NA^(!rowSums(!is.na(dt[selected_cols])))

best_col <- selected_cols[j2]
best_col
#[1] NA   "V3" "V1" "V1" "V4" "V4" "V4"
```

Comment: @UweBlock  Updated the post with best_col

Comment: Thanks, incredible peace of code, still trying to grasp how it works. Just amended your first solution to compute  `best_col` by `dt[, best_col := {v1 <- unlist(.SD)
selected_cols[which(!is.na(v1))[1]]},
.SDcols = selected_cols, by = 1:nrow(dt)]` but you now have already put that in one statement!

Comment: @UweBlock Thanks for the comment.  I would also say that the one with `max.col` will be very fast as well if we are using `base R` instead of looping with `apply`.