# How to access variables of datatable when passed as a parameter to a function?

Tags: r, data.table

I'm new to R and I have searched over google for solution to the below problem.

I have

```
DT = data.table(y=c("a",NA,NA), y_1=c(NA,3,6), y_2=c(1,NA,3), y_3=c(1,1,1)).
```

I want to create a function passing the datatable and the column that needs to be changed.

```
fun <- function(dt, var)

{

dt[,(var) := ifelse(!(is.na(get(var))), get(paste0(var,"1")),
                    ifelse(!(is.na(get(paste0(var,"1")), get(paste0(var,"2")...))]
return(dt)
}
```

I want to replace the values in `y` variable which are `NA`'s with the values in `y_1` if they are not `NULL` or else replace with `y_2` and so on. Like this I want to create a function which can accept different variables but with the same ending.

Update: Uwe, Thanks for pointing that previous question. I found it pretty useful. But, my requirement is slightly different. I need the same update for other variables as well where the values are NA. For example, I need to do it for (x,x_1,x_2,x_3...),(z,z_1,z_2,z_3..) and some other variables apart from y. Is there a way use lapply or function to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are missing one important piece from your question, how you call your `fun` function using the `DT` you have defined.

Comment: I want to pass the datatable and the variable that I want to replace its NA values with.. Like fun(DT,"y")

Comment: Here is the same question (ignoring the wish to grep column names): http://stackoverflow.com/q/37776942/ Alexis' answer there is probably more efficient among those two, fwiw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP is looking for a variant of the `locf` method (last observation carried forward) which is implemented as `zoo::na.locf()` for instance. While `na.locf()` usually is applied on a vector or a column of a data.frame, the OP is looking for a variant which is applied on each row of a `data.table` but restricted to a specific subset of columns. So, the function is being named `na.locl()` (last observation carried *left*).

In addition, the `data.table` is to be updated in place, e.g., without copying. The columns are named in a specific manner, e.g., `x`, `x_1`, `x_2`, `x_3`, etc. So, `x` is kind of a *base name* for the subset of columns.

The function below will look in each row of a specific subset of columns of a given `data.table` for the first non-`NA` column and copies this value to column `x`.

The implementation is based on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37777651/3817004). It includes some plausibilty checks.

```
na.locl <- function(var, dt) {
  checkmate::assert_data_table(dt)
  checkmate::assert_string(var)
  checkmate::assert_choice(var, names(dt))
  ans_val = rep_len(NA_real_, nrow(dt))
  selected_cols <- unlist(lapply(
    var, function(x) stringr::str_subset(names(dt), paste0("^", x, "(_\\d*)?$"))))
  for(col in selected_cols) {
    i = is.na(ans_val) & (!is.na(dt[[col]]))
    ans_val[i] = dt[[col]][i]   
  }
  set(DT, , var, ans_val)
  return(invisible(NULL))
}
```

In addition, the OP has requested to repeat this for other variables. This can be accomplished using `lapply()` with the `na.locl()` function. To demonstrate this, sample data are required.

```
library(data.table)
DT0 <- data.table(y=c("a",NA,NA,NA), y_1=c(NA,3,NA,NA), y_2=c(1,NA,3,NA), y_3=c(1,1,1,NA))
DT <- cbind(DT0, setnames(copy(DT0), stringr::str_replace(names(DT0), "^y", "x")))
DT <- cbind(DT, setnames(copy(DT0), stringr::str_replace(names(DT0), "^y", "zzz")))
DT
#    y y_1 y_2 y_3  x x_1 x_2 x_3 zzz zzz_1 zzz_2 zzz_3
#1:  a  NA   1   1  a  NA   1   1   a    NA     1     1
#2: NA   3  NA   1 NA   3  NA   1  NA     3    NA     1
#3: NA  NA   3   1 NA  NA   3   1  NA    NA     3     1
#4: NA  NA  NA  NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA    NA    NA    NA
```

`y`, `x`, and `zzz` are `NA`except for row 1. After applying the function on DT,

```
dummy <- lapply(c("x", "y", "zzz"), na.locl, dt = DT)

DT
#    y y_1 y_2 y_3  x x_1 x_2 x_3 zzz zzz_1 zzz_2 zzz_3
#1:  a  NA   1   1  a  NA   1   1   a    NA     1     1
#2:  3   3  NA   1  3   3  NA   1   3     3    NA     1
#3:  3  NA   3   1  3  NA   3   1   3    NA     3     1
#4: NA  NA  NA  NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA    NA    NA    NA
```

the missing values in columns `y`, `x`, and `zzz` have been replaced by the next non-`NA` value to the right if available within the subset of columns. Thus, row 4 is all `NA` as no non-`NA` (that's three negations in a row) is available in each of the column subsets.

Comment: Thanks Uwe. I used your previous post to complete my work. But I tested this new function with sample test data and it worked. I'll use this functions and update my code. Thank you very much.